# thermald.service makes problem

Tags: lubuntu, 19.04, temperature

My Notebook

```
 sudo dmidecode -t1
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
        Manufacturer: LENOVO
        Product Name: 2350B58
        Version: ThinkPad T430
        Serial Number: PBVVBLH
        UUID: cdcb8a01-5190-11cb-9490-98976e1f3194
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_2350
        Family: ThinkPad T430
```

tlp is not on my system. Im running Lubuntu

```
Okt 31 13:52:30 Guilmon thermald[743]: error: could not parse file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml
```

I was searching around and found [thermald configuration file for Thinkpad T430](https://gist.github.com/Hermanio/1bf68a09ebf4ffa5e7be32c014066902)

After restart of thermald.service, I get following error.

```
thermald[6496]: sysfs write failed /sys/devices/virtual/powercap/intel-rapl/intel-rapl:0/enabled
```

fine

```
ls -al /sys/devices/virtual/powercap/intel-rapl/enabled 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Okt 31 19:30 /sys/devices/virtual/powercap/intel-rapl/enabled
```

The problem is, I have to stop thermald before I poweroff the system.

```
 dpkg -l| grep sensor
ii  iio-sensor-proxy                              2.5-0ubuntu1                        amd64        IIO sensors to D-Bus proxy
ii  libqt5sensors5:amd64                          5.12.2-1                            amd64        Qt Sensors module
ii  libsensors-config                             1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1                    all          lm-sensors configuration files
ii  libsensors5:amd64                             1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1                    amd64        library to read temperature/voltage/fan sensors
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't have tabs in the .xml file. `<ThermalSensor>` has two tabs in front of it. Use the following corrected `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` file...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ThermalConfiguration>
<Platform>
        <Name>T430</Name>
        <ProductName>*</ProductName>
        <Preference>QUIET</Preference>
        <ThermalSensors>
                <ThermalSensor>
                        <Type>pkg-temp-0</Type>
                        <Path>/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp</Path>
                        <AsyncCapable>1</AsyncCapable>
                </ThermalSensor>
        </ThermalSensors>
        <ThermalZones>
                <ThermalZone>
                        <Type>cpu package</Type>
                        <TripPoints>
                                <TripPoint>
                                        <SensorType>pkg-temp-0</SensorType>
                                        <Temperature>90000</Temperature>
                                        <type>max</type>
                                        <ControlType>PARALLEL</ControlType>
                                        <CoolingDevice>
                                                <index>1</index>
                                                <type>rapl_controller</type>
                                                <influence> 50 </influence>
                                                <SamplingPeriod> 10 </SamplingPeriod>
                                        </CoolingDevice>
                                        <CoolingDevice>
                                                <index>2</index>
                                                <type>intel_pstate</type>
                                                <influence> 40 </influence>
                                                <SamplingPeriod> 10 </SamplingPeriod>
                                        </CoolingDevice>
                                        <CoolingDevice>
                                                <index>3</index>
                                                <type>intel_powerclamp</type>
                                                <influence> 30 </influence>
                                                <SamplingPeriod> 10 </SamplingPeriod>
                                        </CoolingDevice>
                                        <CoolingDevice>
                                                <index>4</index>
                                                <type>cpufreq</type>
                                                <influence> 20 </influence>
                                                <SamplingPeriod> 10 </SamplingPeriod>
                                        </CoolingDevice>
                                        <CoolingDevice>
                                                <index>5</index>
                                                <type>Processor</type>
                                                <influence> 10 </influence>
                                                <SamplingPeriod> 10 </SamplingPeriod>
                                        </CoolingDevice>
                                </TripPoint>
                        </TripPoints>
                </ThermalZone>
        </ThermalZones>
</Platform>
</ThermalConfiguration>
```

Comment: Zhanks @heuynnema I draw thermald from git.

Comment: @nobody I know that you got the .xml file from git. Did you try my .xml file?

Comment: sorry  @heuynnema  I had to make a new install. and make it short and painless `sudo apt purge thermald`

Comment: @nobody did you end up reinstalling thermald, or just give up? Did you try my .xml file first?

Comment: @heymenna, I have  do reinstall the whole os, because I format it instead of bionic. :(